Chartjs react initially hidden LegendItems
how can I set {hidden:true} on all LegendItems? If I set hidden property to true the legend item is only striked-through but the graph is still displayed. Any ideas?
Thank you!
I already tried this:
const options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: datasets.length > 1, // display legend if multiple datasets provided
            labels: {
                generateLabels: (chart) => {
                    return datasets.map((dataset, i) => {
                        return {
                            text: dataset.label,
                            hidden: true,
                        };
                    })
                }
            }
        },
        annotation: {
            annotations: []
        }
    },
    scale: {
        ticks: {
            precision: 0
        }
    }
};


The standard way to hide (or show) a dataset in chart.js is to use chart.setDatasetVisibility.
To hide all datasets, you may use:
chart.data.datasets.forEach((_, i) => chart.setDatasetVisibility(i, false));
chart.update();

Live snippet:


const data = {
    labels: ['2024', '2025', '2026', '2027'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: Array.from({length: 4}, () => 10 +  Math.random() * 10)
        },
        {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            data: Array.from({length: 4}, () => 10 + Math.random() * 10)
        }
    ]
};

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: data.datasets.length > 1, // display legend if multiple datasets provided
            }
        },
    },
};

const chart = new Chart(document.querySelector('#myChart'), config);
chart.data.datasets.forEach((_, i) => chart.setDatasetVisibility(i, false));
chart.update();
<div style="min-height: 60vh">
    <canvas id="myChart">
    </canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.2/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>



Besides not doing what you expected, generateLabels has the disadvantage that it requires
other properties
to be defined; with just text and hidden, it will not display the color and style of the dataset, nor
will it hide/show the dataset unless you define custom onclick handlers.
